# Indexing issue while adding dynamic Input text in the form in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am adding dynamic input text box on button click, when add button is clicked one input box is added to the form.
but when i remove any input box[enter image description here][1] except last one the second last input gets empty. Do not know what is the problem.

This is HTML part

```html
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5">
      <div
        class="form-row"
        *ngFor="let recommendation of recommendationList; let i=index"
      >
        <div class="form-group float-label-control col-md-11">
          <input
            name="RecommendationNote{{i}}"
            placeholder="Recommendation Note"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="recommendation.RecommendationNote"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span
            class="btn btn-danger"
            (click)="removeRecommendationInput(i)"
            *ngIf="recommendationList.length > 1"
            >Delete</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0; padding-right: 0;">
        <span class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRecommendationInput(i)">Add</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Add and remove functions

```js
    addRecommendationInput() {   
        this.recommendationList.push(new GeneralRecommendation());
    }    

    removeRecommendationInput(index) {
        this.recommendationList.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am not quite sure what your question is. Neither can I imagine whats happening. Can you provide a reproducable sample? E.g. in stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrvr9u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts 
 Go to the link. Add more than 3 input boxes by clicking on Add button and put some values in them, then remove the 2nd or any input which is not last one, then u will see that the value of 2nd last input field gets cleared.That's the issue i am facing.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrvr9u?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" in your input and this will solve your issue.